# Возможно ли перехватить вызов хранимой процедуры Ado.net?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

Есть приложение с ado.net и mssql.

Можно ли перехватить запрос к базе данных из вне? Нельзя менять код в приложенни, можно лишь написать другое. Хванимые процедуры тоже нельзя менять.

Стоит задача, в некотором моде приложения не давать изменять состоянии базы данных.(не давать в том смысле при завершении операции откатывать изменения)

Думал, перехватить вызов хранимой процедуры и обернуть все в транзакцию.

У кого какие идеи?

Comment: доступа к бд нет вообще или только хп нельзя менять?

Comment: Доступ к бд есть, хранимки нельзя менять.

Comment: запретите доступ приложению к бд

Comment: @Anatol Нельзя, нужно чтоб приложения получило данные и при попытке изменить, просто их не изменяло.

Comment: разрешите чтение и запретите запись, тот же хрен, только в другой руке

Comment: @Anatol дак упадет с эксепшеном на нехватку прав

Comment: ну если нельзя и так, то ставьте триггеры на таблицы, которые предполагаются к изменению

Comment: На уровне c# можно как-то откатить?

Answer (score 0):

Для каждой таблицы создайте пустой триггер с типом instead of insert, update, delete (совсем пустой нельзя, но можно внутри триггера просто set сделать). он заменяет собой операции и, фактически, прозрачно их пропускает, не применяя никаких изменений.

Пример для теста:

```
create table testtable (id int identity (1, 1), value int);

insert into dbo.testtable (value) values  (1), (2), (3);

select * from dbo.testtable as t
go

create trigger unmodifiable_testtable on dbo.testtable 
instead of insert, update, delete as 
begin set nocount on end;

go
insert into dbo.testtable (value) values  (4);

update dbo.testtable set value = 5 where value = 2;

delete from dbo.testtable where value = 3;

select * from dbo.testtable as t;

drop table dbo.testtable
```

Код создания триггера можно сгенерировать для каждой таблицы, используя динамический SQL и системные представления, типа sys.tables.